# React Navigation - Nested Redirect

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have following Navigation Structure

```
const HomeTabNavigator = () => (
    <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="HomeStackNavigator"/>
        <Tab.Screen name="SearchStackNavigator"/>
        <Tab.Screen name="AccountStackNavigator" />
    </Tab.Navigator>
);

const HomeStackNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <HomeStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
            <HomeStack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen}/>
        </HomeStack.Navigator>
    )
}

const SearchStackNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <SearchStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
            <SearchStack.Screen name="SearchScreen" component={SearchScreen}/>
            <SearchStack.Screen name="SearchDetailScreen" component={SearchDetailScreen}/>
        </SearchStack.Navigator>
    );
}

const AccountStackNavigator = () => {
    return(  
        <AccountStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
            <AccountStack.Screen name="AccountScreen" component={AccountScreen}/>
            <AppointmentStack.Screen name="ItemListScreen" component={ItemListScreen}/>
            <AppointmentStack.Screen name="ItemDetailScreen" component={ItemDetailScreen}/>
        </AccountStack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

From any screen, I want to navigate to `ItemDetailScreen` found in `AccountStackNavigator`, let's say, I want to navigate from `HomeScreen`. However when I click on back button of `ItemDetailScreen` it must redirect me to `ItemListScreen` and the back button on this screen must redirect me to `AccountScreen`.

I am using the following screen for redirect.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('AccountStackNavigator', {
    screen: 'AppointmentListScreen',
    params: {
        screen: 'AccountScreen'
    }
});
```

This redirects me from `HomeScreen` to `AppointmentListScreen` and when I click back here, it redirects me to `AccountScreen` which is perfect. Now here is my Issue, when I use this code.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('AccountStackNavigator', {
    screen: 'AppointmentDetailScreen',
    params: {
        screen: 'AppointmentListScreen',
        params: {
            screen: 'AccountScreen'
        }
    }
});
```

It redirects me to `AppointmentDetailScreen` perfectly, however, when I click on back button here, it redirects me to `HomeScreen` whereas I want it to be redirected with the following flow.

```
AppointmentDetailScreen > AppointmentListScreen > AccountScreen
```

I have tried so many way to achieve this, but nothing seems to work for me, can anyone help in right direction please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was frustrating using `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` to achieve this mainly because it lacks animation between switching screens giving user a weird experience, hence I moved to `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs` and it worked well.